# Build automation in perforce source control when file checked in

Tags: .net, build-process, build-automation

I am using perforce as source control. I just want to automate building process. When any once checkin the file into branch created, build should automatically start and send result to the user through mail. Can i achieve it by coding in .net or any tools are available?

Answer (score 0):

To receive email notifications for checked in changes, you can use the Perforce Review Daemon. See the following docs:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html#DB5-74050

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Configuring-The-New-Perforce-Review-Daemon-p4review2-py

For any other automatic scripted actions after files are checked in, you can use a submit trigger. See the following docs:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html#d0e15471

http://answers.perforce.com (search 'triggers')

Let me know if this answers your question.